# Cassandra IN clause on index

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, database, nosql

Assume a simple table with one insert (or without this insert, doesn't really matter).

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 x int,
 y int,
 z int,
 PRIMARY KEY (x, y, z)
);


create index z_index on test (z);

insert into test(x, y, z) values (1,2,3);
```

I struggle to understand why **I cannot query with an in clause** on the index z:

> cqlsh:test> select * from test where z in (3);
>       Bad Request: PRIMARY KEY part z cannot be restricted (preceding part y is either not                 restricted or by a non-EQ relation)

It is possible with a simple equals predicate:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from test where z = 3;

 x | y | z
---+---+---
 1 | 2 | 3

(0 rows)
```

I thought having an index on z would keep a mapping from specific values of z to rows but this assumption seems wrong.

Why this doesn't work the way I expected? I guess the index works differently.

EDIT: I am using [cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.6 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

Answer (score 7):

While the documentation on DataStax is normally really good, I couldn't find anything discussing the details behind this.  I did however, run across this article called [A deep look at the CQL WHERE clause](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2015/06/deep-look-cql-where-clause/).  The second section titled "**WHERE clause restrictions for SELECT statements**" has several paragraphs discussing the `IN` restriction.

To paraphrase, it basically says this:

> For single column keys, the IN operator is allowed without restriction.  For composite primary keys, I have to use the = operator on the first N-1 columns of the partition key in order to use the IN operator on the last column.

In your case, `x` is your partition key, which means that `x` is the only column that will support the `IN` operator of CQL.  If you really do need to be able to support `IN` queries on column `z`, then you would have to de-normalize your data, and build a (redundant) table designed to support that query.  For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
 x int,
 y int,
 z int,
 PRIMARY KEY (z)
);
```

...would support the query, but the values of `z` may not be unique.  In that case, you could define `x` and/or `y` as a `LIST<int>` and that would do it.

Also, DataStax *does* have documentation available on [when not to use an index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__selectInNot), and they state that the same conditions apply to the use of the `IN` operator.

> Under most conditions, using IN in the WHERE clause is not
>   recommended. Using IN can degrade performance because usually many
>   nodes must be queried. For example, in a single, local data center
>   cluster with 30 nodes, a replication factor of 3, and a consistency
>   level of LOCAL_QUORUM, a single key query goes out to two nodes, but
>   if the query uses the IN condition, the number of nodes being queried
>   are most likely even higher, up to 20 nodes depending on where the
>   keys fall in the token range.

Comment: I would adjust to "The last column in the PRIMARY key supports the IN operator." - just tested it by using IN for last clustering key.

Comment: http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/11/05/breaking-down-the-cql-where-clause/ not working

Comment: @Scaramouche updated with a link to a new post containing the same info.